# ActiveRecord array count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i am trying to count an # of objects in an array using a block, like this:

```
cc = u.cookies.count {|n| n.opened}
```

This return 3, which is wrong. I went a step further, and did this:

```
cc = u.cookies.count {|n| false}
```

which should always return 0, but it returns 3!!!.

This return 0, just like it should:

```
[1,2,3,4].count {|n| false}
```

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cookies
end
```

What's going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`u.cookies` is `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not an array.

So what ever the block is, the result won't change, you need to do:

```
cc = u.cookies.where(:opened => true).count
```